# Number formatting in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a question regarding number formatting in asp.net mvc razor.

What I want is that numbers have a thousand delimiter. I would prefer `'` but anything else would do to.
So in my code I added

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")] 
public int FooBar { get; set; }
```

In one page I get `2'000` and in another page it displays `10.000`.

Maybe one important point culture is set to neutral in web.config.

I really would like to understand why there are different delimiters in different pages.

`FooBar` is created as:

```
<pre><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FooBar)&nbsp;&#181;l</td></pre>
```

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Can you post the bit of code where `FooBar` is used on the pages?

Comment: FooBar is used <pre><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FooBar)&nbsp;&#181;l</td></pre>

Comment: is that for the page where you get 2'000 as well as 10.000? Are you using the same model on both pages?

Comment: You are right it is not the same model. The side is database first. So I checked the two models and couldn't find a difference. Still I can't figure why the display format is different.

Comment: I could make out the source of all evil. in one side controller I found the code to set the culture. That's the reason why I have to different delimiters in different pages.

Is there a way how I could force the delimiter (only numbers) to (')?